# WPF: Is there any way to make print preview for richtextbox content?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, print-preview

i'm making a text editor with richtextbox of wpf, and i wanna print the formatted text written by it. But the printed result was too bad, so i wanna make a print preview dialog. unfortunately, for now, i cannot find the way to make that.

Could I get any solution to make anything to work a "print preview" utility(dialog, control etc.) in wpf richtexbox?

Comment: Can you clarify what "was too bad" exactly mean and how the actual result differed from what you had expected to see

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The rtb editor that i'd made has some padding value, but after printing, the content on the paper does not have that padding, i mean, the contents start at left-top point of the paper having no any spaces, while i'm using 'PrintVisual', 'PrintDocument(IDocumentPaginator~~~)' like [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-save-load-and-print-richtextbox-content). And then, i made temp xps file by source in code-behind, but in that way, the content could not have formatted text. So far, i cannot make the other solution. :(